# Can I enter Spain with a Ukrainian passport traveling from a non-EU country?

Tags: covid-19, spain, cuba, ukrainian-citizens, cuban-citizens

I have dual citizenship (Cuban and Ukrainian), and I currently reside in Cuba. I don't have Ukrainian residency.

Since July 27th, Ukraine is included in the list of countries that are not considered at risk for Spain. This can be checked [here](https://www.mscbs.gob.es/profesionales/saludPublica/ccayes/alertasActual/nCov/spth.htm).

Do I have to be a Ukrainian resident to be able to enter Spain? Would coming from Cuba disallow me from entering Spain?

Comment: For COVID 19 rules it is not your citizenship but where you have been recently that determinds whether you can get in. Usually, that is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> NB: Travel is currently ill-advised unless you're fully vaccinated due to very high cases levels all around the world. Consider postponing your trip or instead traveling to a country where you can get vaccinated locally, such as the US, if you haven't been vaccinated just yet.

Flying directly to Spain? No, unless you've been vaccinated with an EU-approved vaccine (which aren't available in Cuba yet, as they're using local ones instead?) as described by @mlc. But there's always the Croatia loophole, which has been available for more than a year now to gain access to any EU country regardless of your residency. Croatia is visa-free for Ukrainian citizens so this option will work for you.

[According to IATA](https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php), the following foreign citizens may enter Spain:

> passengers arriving from Austria, Belgium, Bulgaria, **Croatia**, Cyprus, Czechia, Denmark, Estonia, Finland, France, Germany, Greece, Hungary, Iceland, Ireland (Rep.), Italy, Latvia, Liechtenstein, Lithuania, Luxembourg, Malta, Netherlands, Norway, Poland, Portugal, Romania, Slovakia, Slovenia, Sweden or Switzerland;

So passengers traveling from Ukraine are not included unless there's residents. However there's a "loophole" where you can first enter Croatia and then fly to any EU country of your choosing. The IATA page has the following requirements for Croatia:

> - passengers traveling as tourists with proof of paid accommodation;

The Croatian National Tourist Board [confirms this](https://croatia.hr/en-GB/coronavirus-2019-ncov-q-and-a):

> Third-country nationals not covered by the above mentioned points may
> enter the Republic of Croatia from third countries if they are:
>
> - persons who travel for tourist reasons and have confirmation of paid accommodation in a hotel, camp, private renter or rented vessel
>   and other form of tourist accommodation or are owners of houses or
>   vessels in the Republic of Croatia;

> Persons referred to in items 7,
> 8, and 9 will be allowed to enter the Republic of Croatia with:
>
> - Presentation of a certificate of negative PCR or rapid antigen test for SARS-CoV-2 listed on the Joint List of Rapid Antigen Tests
>   Mutually Recognized by the Member States of the European Union,
>   published by the European Commission, if the test result is not older
>   than 48 hours testing until arrival at the border crossing.

So what you could do is fly from Cuba to Croatia (I'm seeing an Air France flight that could work, as France still allows for transit), stay there for a day and then fly to Spain. Note that you'll need a COVID test in both Cuba and Croatia. On the way back you could just fly straight from Spain to Cuba.

Comment: Yeah, they are using local vaccines here in Cuba. I will certainly consider this!

Comment: I did some research and I found that a part of Croatia, including Zagreb, is a green zone for Spain, that is, you wouldn't have to present a Covid test.

Answer (score 3):

According to [the link you provide](https://www.mscbs.gob.es/en/profesionales/saludPublica/ccayes/alertasActual/nCov/spth.htm), residents of countries like Ukraine may use that exemption to enter Spain only if

> siempre que procedan directamente de ellos, hayan transitado exclusivamente por otros países incluidos en la lista o hayan realizado únicamente tránsitos internacionales en aeropuertos situados en países que no constan en el anexo.

Or, in English:

> provided that they come directly from them, have transited exclusively through other countries included in the list or have carried out only international transits in airports located in countries that do not appear in the annex.

(Spanish government translation at the link above)

As you would not be coming directly from Ukraine, you would not qualify for this exemption.

As of this writing, there is a separate exemption for travelers who "dispone de un certificado de haber sido vacunado con una vacuna autorizada y con una pauta completa administrada hace más de 14 días" (in English according to the government translation, "have a certificate of being fully vaccinated with an EMA/OMS authorized vaccine, and the last dose was administered more than 14 days ago.")

Apparently the fine rules for this exemption are still being developed, so you may wish to do more research if you believe you qualify for it.

Comment: In this case, it would seem, being a resident of Cuba is one problem and, if vaccinated, what type another.